# zipalign not installed with Java SDK / JRE

Tags: java, android, sdk, apk, zipalign

I need to zip-align an APK file after I re-signed it with a specific cert. Everything worked fine with keytool and jarsigner. However, the zipalign tool was not installed with Java SDK 8 Update 92 (inlcuding JRE in same version). I am running Windows 10 x64.

Also, the Android Studio IDE did not come with zipalign tool. I crawled many forums and also stackoverflow but did not find any solution. In former times, zipalign was always installed with Java JRE in BIN directory.

Where do I get the zip-align tool?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware `zipalign` is an Android specific tool, not a Java tool. Why would it be included in the JDK/JRE? This tool is part of the Android SDK, more specifically it's part of the Android build tools.

Look in your Android SDK directory, e.g.:

`~/android-sdks/build-tools/25.0.1/zipalign`

Replace `~/android-sdks` with the directory in which you have installed the Android SDK. Replace `25.0.1` with any of the build tools version(s) you have installed (25.0.1 is the most current right now).